# Django: password reset ReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django, passwords, reset

I'm having trouble getting password_reset_confirm to work. I have looked at numerous solutions, but none seem to be working for me.

**urls.py**: (in particular, the third line)

```
(r'^resetpassword/passwordsent/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done', name="reset_password"),
(r'^resetpassword/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', name="reset_password"),
(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)-(?P<token>,+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
(r'^reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
```

the **password_reset_email.html**:

```
{% load url from future %}
{% autoescape off %}
Someone asked for password reset for email {{ email }}. Follow the link below:
{{ protocol}}://{{ domain }}{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Everything seems to be working fine, until I submit my e-mail and get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb64': 'OQ', u'token': u'3n2-0fee9d3f98dad36e63d8'}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['/$reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', 'reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)-(?P<token>,+)/$']
```

I am using Django 1.6.
Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [this suspiciously similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143393/noreversematch-on-password-reset-confirm) question?

Comment: Use name or the full name of view.

Comment: Yes I have, I changed my url conf to be the full path, but it still hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can see from the exception what's going on, although it's a little hard to spot. If you look at what patterns it tried:

```
2 pattern(s) tried: ['/$reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', 'reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)-(?P<token>,+)/$']
```

You should notice that the first pattern is the one that should generally match, in the sense that it accepts a token with a `-` in it. But it has a stray `$` prepending the rest of its content, so actually it can't match anything:

```
'/$reset/...'
```

You don't show the `urls.py` line that establishes that pattern - the third line you refer to can only match a token consisting of nothing but commas:

```
(?P<token>,+)
```

So while I can safely say that you need to correct your `urls.py`, I cannot say exactly where you need to correct it. If you intend to match that `urls.py` line, you should update the `token` group regexp to accept your actual token values, and should figure out why the other one is around to match at all. That said, if `-` is a valid character to appear as part of your token I think you'll find it easier overall to use `/` as a divider between your `uidb64` field and your token, as your first regexp does except for the stray `$`.