# Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with keyword arguments (followed by arguemnt list) not found

Tags: django, python-3.x

New to django here. I am trying to implement password reset functionality in my app.I am using the console email backend.

I am using django 2.x and python 3.5.x. When I enter the email and hit
submit I get following error
Kindly tell me how to get rid of this error.

```
NoReverseMatch at /reset/. Reversefor'password_reset_confirm' with
keyword arguments '{'uidb64': 'NQ', 'token':'533-3b115e87321ed5f71bbe'}'     
not found
```

root urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
import boards
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('boards/', include('boards.urls')),
    path('reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='boards/password_reset.html',
        email_template_name='boards/password_reset_email.html',
        subject_template_name='boards/password_reset_subject.txt',
    ), name='password_reset'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
        template_name='boards/password_reset_done.html'
    ), name='password_reset_done'),
    re_path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
    template_name='boards/password_reset_confirm.html'),
    name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/complete/',     auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
    template_name='boards/password_reset_complete.html'

), name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('setting/password/',     auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name =     'boards/password_change.html'),name='password_change'),
    path('setting/password/done/',     auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='boards/password_cha    nge_done.html'), name='password_change_done'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

It shows error during template rendering at the following line

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

Comment: `re_path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>    /'...)` looks like an invalid pattern: it first of all is `path(..)` syntax, and furthermore should have a regex part (or in case of a path a path converter).

Comment: It shows connection refused error when I use path. And the tutorial I took help from does it using  the  above pattern.

Comment: can you please try with re_path(r'^reset/<uidb64>/<token> /', your view )

Comment: @shakil I am doing it with that only. That long blank space is a typo I am gonna fix

Comment: @AlisaDarya i am saying to start with **r^** .  normally i see all example in django doc with re_path , starting with **r^**

Comment: Tried doing that. Still doesn't work

Comment: can you please tell me `./manage.py show_urls` running this command listing/showing  your password_reset_confirm url or not ?

Comment: i found like a similar post, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143393/noreversematch-on-password-reset-confirm?rq=1)

Comment: Use path `path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
    template_name='boards/password_reset_confirm.html'),
    name='password_reset_confirm'),`

Comment: @Shakil unknown command:show_urls